# jquery aren't working on the url that i load in div(.load)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, assembly.load

Let's say that in a document I have a div and a button that will show the div:

```
<div id="dvExternal" style="display: none;">
</div>

<button type="button" id="btnShow">
<span>Show</span>
</button>
```

and a jquery that commands it to show:

```
$("#btnShow").click(function(){
     $("#dvExternal").css("display","block");
     $("#dvExternal").load("whattheitsnotworking.php");
});
```

and that page contains jquery functions, php, iframe etc.

The problem is when it loads on the div the jquery on that page isn't working.

Thanks in advance :)

The page that I was trying to load in the div contains(for example):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)){
     $("#inputDate").val("<?php echo date("Y"); ?>");
});
</script>
```

This script doesn't load or work.

Comment: What does that mean: "in some cases / isn't working"? What happens? Nothing? Any error messages? Does the world implode? Are we meant to guess? What does the debugging console output?

Comment: works fine for me http://damienkeitel.com/pr.php

Comment: in some cases because the jquery date picker is working

Comment: Can we get a link to the page so we can debug in console or at least provide the code for the page loaded into the div.

Comment: @DamienKeitel - it's done sir, you can now check again the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use live function of jquery, it will help you...

```
 $("#btnShow").live("click",function(){
    $("#dvExternal").css("display","block");
    $("#dvExternal").load("whattheitsnotworking.php");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js">
```

in the parent page head

I have it working @ http://www.damienkeitel.com/pr.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function( e )){
     $( "#inputDate" ).val( "<?php echo date('Y'); ?>" );
}
</script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function( e ){
     $( "#inputDate" ).val();
});
</script>
```

jQuery .val() is only to get a value of an element.

To set a value you can use this method.

```
$( "#inputDate" ).attr( "value", "<?php echo date('Y'); ?>" );
```

you had one to many ) after function(e) and also didnt close off the function with );

Comment: hahah, sorry my mistake.. but that is not the problem.. the page that i was loading on the div is working when it is not loaded in the div. that's only a typo error.. sorry :)

Comment: So you are trying to change the date on the jQuery UI date pciker and this isnt working on it?

Comment: nope, this is just one of the many script that wasn't loading or working.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site with the problems please.

Comment: Sorry, but how? :) I'm new to this.

Comment: I guess your using xampp or wamp. Can you http://pastebin.com/ the whole script loaded into the div please.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. Every jquery doesn't work. Except for the jquery ui. But every thing works fine when it is loaded outside the div

Comment: Without actually knowing what is inside the other script, we really can't debug the errors or find any problem code.